# Error with HTTP header when submit twice the same request

Tags: node.js, express, mysqljs

Hi there I'm doing a very simple API using NodeJS, ExpressJS and MySQLJs. I have a little form that make the request `login` request to the server. The problem I have is when I'm trying to do the same request twice after the first has been finished, the server answer me with a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I was using this tutorial in order to make my code a little bit cleaner. I've changed a little because I think class makes the code cleaner than using `functions`.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-the-asynchronous-nature-of-nodejs--net-36183

This is the full backtrace of the error I have

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at User.<anonymous> (/home/ismael/Projects/internal_project/app.js:84:9)
    at User.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ismael/Projects/internal_project/model/user.js:20:14)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ismael/Projects/internal_project/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
    at Query._callback (/home/ismael/Projects/internal_project/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:468:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/home/ismael/Projects/internal_project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/home/ismael/Projects/internal_project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/home/ismael/Projects/internal_project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ismael/Projects/internal_project/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:278:23)
```

This is my main javascript where I define the main structure of my simple application. In the log I can see that the second request is enter in success callback, what am I missing?

```
app.post( '/login/', function(req, res){
  user.on('success', function(result){
    logger.debug( '[SUCCESS]' );

    res.cookie('user', { name : result.name, id : result.id  });
    res.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    res.status(200).end( JSON.stringify({success : true}) );
  });
  user.on('failure', function(reason){
    logger.debug( '[FAILURE]' );

    res.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    res.status(400).send( JSON.stringify({success: false}) );
  });
  user.on('error', function(error){
    // logger.debug( '[ERROR]' );
    //
    // res.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    // res.status(500).send( JSON.stringify({ error: 'Internal error' }) );
  });
  user.login( req.body.username, req.body.password );
});
```

And this is the login method of the User class

```
login ( username, password ){
    var that = this;

    this.sql.query( "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ? AND password = ?", [ username, password ], function(error, result, fields){
      // if ( error ){
      //   that.emit('error', error);
      //   return true;
      // }

      if ( result.length == 0 ){
        that.emit( 'failure' );
        return true;
      }

      if ( result.length >= 1 ){
        that.emit( 'success', result[0] );

        return true;
      }

    });
  }
```

I'm using this Javascript in front side to get all the values from the login form and send it to the API.

**main.js**

```
(function(){
  var _loginForm = {},
      _loginUsername = {},
      _loginPassword = {},
      _loginConfig = {
        url : '/login/',
        method : 'POST'
      },
      _loginRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var
  _onLoginRequest = function(){
    console.log( this );

    if ( this.readyState == 4 ){
      JSON.parse(this.responseText)
    }
  },
  _onLoginSubmit = function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

    _loginRequest.onreadystatechange = _onLoginRequest;
    _loginRequest.open( _loginConfig.method, _loginConfig.url, true );
    _loginRequest.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    _loginRequest.send(JSON.stringify({
      username : _loginUsername.value,
      password : _loginPassword. value
    }));
  },
  _onDomLoad = function(evt){
    _loginForm = document.getElementById( 'login-form' );
    _loginUsername = document.getElementById( 'username' );
    _loginPassword = document.getElementById( 'password' );

    _loginForm.addEventListener( 'submit', _onLoginSubmit );
  };

  document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', _onDomLoad );

})();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works the same way using `send`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering event handlers for every request. The problem is, you're not removing any of the request handlers afterwards.

For example, if you did 10 POST requests to the login endpoint, and then you do the 11th. If the 11th's is successful, the `success` event is triggered for the current request but also all the other 10.

The reason you're getting `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` is because the event listener is being triggered for a HTTP request that already completed.

The solution is to architect this different. The EventListener is *not* a good model for calling functions and getting results. EventListener is good for things that can trigger many times. In this case you don't want that, you only want 1 success or 1 failure per request.

The right model for this is:

A) A simple function call. It can return information related to it's success and throw an exception if it failed.

B) Return promises. Resolve them if login was successful, Reject them if not.

C) Use async/await. Again: return the `result` if it was successful, throw an error if not.

D) Use the callback pattern that you're already using with express. So pass a callback with a `err` and `result` parameter.

The last option might be preferable because you're working with a framework that doesn't support Promises and async/await well.

Comment: Can you put a little example of D option? I'm new to NodeJS so I don't know how to do it properly. Thanks very much !

Comment: I understand what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Create User object inside `app.post` api call instead of creating it globally.

Comment: I still have the same problem.

Comment: Can u attach the sample code on which you are trying this ? Need to see the complete code.

Comment: I updated the question with the main javascript I'm using for the POST request.